# Breeze Query: compare two columns on Related entity

Tags: one-to-many, breeze, predicate, one-to-one

Using Breeze, how can I compare two columns on a related property of an entity?

```
 public class TableA{
   public ICollection<TableB> TableBEntity {get; set;}
}

public class TableB{
  public TableC TableCEntity {get; set;}
}

public class TableC {
  public string columnA { get; set;}
  public string columnB { get; set;}
}

var subpredicate = Predicate.create('TableCEntity.columnA', FilterQueryOp.Equals, 'TableCEntity.columnB');

var predicate = Predicate.create('TableBEntity', FilterQueryOp.Any, subpredicate);

var query1 = EntityQuery.from('TableB')
           .where(subpredicate);

var query2 = EntityQuery.from('TableA')
             .where(predicate );
```

query1 above executes without error. However query2 gives me the error:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'TableCEntity' on type 'TableA'.

It seems as the subpredicate is not properly evaluated and it searches for the property `TableCEntity` on `TableA` instead of on `TableB`. If I change the subpredicate to

```
var subpredicate = Predicate.create('TableCEntity.columnA', FilterQueryOp.Equals, 'asamplevalue');
```

then, query2 works find. It just does not work the right side of the predicate is a record's column.

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The breeze 'any' and 'all' operators require that the property returned by the first expression ( "orders" in the example below) be a nonscalar navigation property. i.e. a navigation property that returns a collection.  The subpredicate is then is just a simple predicate against the type returned by the first expression.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
    .where("orders", "any", "freight", ">", 950);
```

with predicates this would be expressed as follows

```
var p2 = Predicate.create("freight", ">", 950);
var p1 = Predicate.create("orders", "any", p2);
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees").where(p1);
```

In your case, i'm not sure what you are trying to do with your 'query2'.  'query2' appears to be a query over a collection of 'TableB' entities returned from 'TableA', but the 'subpredicate' deals with 'TableC' entities.

If this doesn't help, it might be easier to assist if you could restate your TableA, B and C names with table names that are a bit more intuitive and pluralize the collection property names.

Hope this helps.